# How to redirect non www and http to https with www?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, no-www

How to redirect non www and http to https with www via htaccess?
I want to redirect old folder to home page like http://.test.com/test1/about.php to https://www.test.com

Comment: Did you try to use the Search bar at the top of the website?

Answer (score 0):

Put these line in your .htaccess file in root directory of your webserver:

```
Redirect 301 /test1/about.php to https://www.test.com
```

Also make sure that you haven't disable .htaccess in your apache config.

Comment: but i want to redirect all folder and page in one code

Comment: How to redirect non www to https with www?

Comment: You can check document of htaccess for your purpose. If you want to force www in the url your can try htaccess rewrite.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.test.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

Try this conf one on your server configuration :

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```